# Which software to choose to power a very simple shopping-cart where I am going to sell software?

Tags: shopping-cart

I want to power a very simple shopping-cart where I will be selling software. I've checked a bunch of them already and still can't find what I need. Most of shopping-carts don't have "virtual product" functionality. Among those that have this feature are PrestaShop and Magento.

Presta doesn't have this feature implemented very well. I don't remember details about what I didn't like in Presta but as far as I remember the feature was not very well implemented: no ability to disable shipping, not possible to specify that people must be able to buy one item only (which is software license), no ability to set endless quantity for the products, etc.

Then I checked Magento, it has this feature implemented almost perfectly (still have to figure out how to disable quantity). However I heard that Magento is rather slow and frankly speaking this software looks like overkill. It has huge number of features and there are many many lines of code while I simply need the ability to register users, let them log in to the customer area and provide them with either download link to the already purchased software or the "buy now" link.

Do you by chances know of such software?

Comment: hm...I've just rechecked zen cart, may be they released a new version or something like that but it seems that the virtual products feature is there. I am still looking into it but this one looks very promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decided to use zen cart after all